# Is it possible to retrieve the whole sentence in the JSON generated by the spaCy IOB converter?

Tags: python, json, spacy, spacy-3

After following the steps to convert data in IOB format to spaCy compatible JSON; the value [`"raw": string`](https://spacy.io/api/data-formats#json-input) supposed to represent the sentence appears as "null" in my JSON.

Here is an excerpt from my data (`test.iob`):

```
GRIMALTE    B-PERS
AMANT   O
DE  O
LA  O
dame    B-PERS
Gradisse    B-PERS
narre   O
sommairement    O
Les O
amoureux    O
regredz O
de  O
Flamete B-PERS
,   O
qui O
furent  O
occasion    O
qu' O
il  O
cherchast   O
moyen   O
d'  O
y   O
remedier    O
Chapitre    O
premier O
.   O
BRief   O
traictie    O
par O
Jehan   B-PERS

... continue
```

Then, I entered the command :

```
python -m spacy convert -c auto -s -n 1 -t json ./test.iob . --lang fr
```

finally, in output, I get the following JSON, but without the `"raw"` value :

```
[
  {
    "id":0,
    "paragraphs":[
      {
        "raw":null,
        "sentences":[
          {
            "tokens":[
              {
                "id":0,
                "orth":"GRIMALTE",
                "space":" ",
                "tag":"-",
                "ner":"U-PERS"
              },
              {
                "id":1,
                "orth":"AMANT",
                "space":" ",
                "tag":"-",
                "ner":"O"
              },
              {
                "id":2,
                "orth":"DE",
                "space":" ",
                "tag":"-",
                "ner":"O"
              },
              {
                "id":3,
                "orth":"LA",
                "space":" ",
                "tag":"-",
                "ner":"O"
              },

... continue
```

I would really like to retrieve this sentence (in the "raw" value) to be able to create from the entities of the JSON a training set as follows:

```
[
("GRIMALTE AMANT DE LA dame Gradisse narre sommairement Les amoureux regredz de Flamete , qui furent occasion qu' il cherchast moyen d' y remedier Chapitre premier ", {'entities': [(0, 8, 'PERS'), (21, 25, 'PERS'), (26, 34, 'PERS'), (78, 85, 'PERS')]})
... continue
]
```

Could this be because my IOB file does not contain white spaces between sentences? (because looking in the [examples of the spaCy converter](https://github.com/explosion/spaCy/tree/master/extra/example_data/ner_example_data) it does not seem to impact the iob to json conversion)

If you have any leads on this issue, thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because the original corpus in this format doesn't contain whitespace information, you can't generate the original/correct `raw` sentence, so it's left as `null`. `spacy train` will take into account whether there's whitespace information or not while training and evaluating, so it's possible to train with or without `raw`, or from a mixture of docs with and without `raw`.

If you are training with spacy, you don't want to convert this data to the format with a text string and character offsets. It will cause problems if you have tokens like `l'`, which will be tokenized incorrectly if there's a following space. You should be able to use `spacy train` from the JSON format with `"ner"` tags.